# Handling duplicate embedded CSS Selectors across SVG documents

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

When embedding an SVG document into an HTML document using the `<svg>` element, what mechanisms do we currently have avoid CSS collisions resulting from embedded CSS class names being identical?

My use case is:

1. User exports two different Visio diagrams to SVG.
2. Both SVG documents are loaded into the same HTML document using SnapSVG.

One solution is to parse out the CSS selectors in each SVG document, rename them and replace all occurrences of that class within the SVG doc.

What other solutions are there that are nicer than this?

Comment: `<style scoped>` provided you're only targetting Chrome and Firefox with a pref change.

Comment: Put each SVG in its own `<iframe>`?

Comment: You can use Shadow DOM to insert svg element.